# Rails - how do I show an Add Favourite button to users who are not logged in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to display an "Add to Favourites" button to users that are not logged in so that they can see that logged in users can add posts (in this case) to their favourites.

Here's the current code:

**routes.rb**

```
resources :users do
  resources :favourites
end
resources :favourites, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

**posts_helper.rb (I'll move this application_helper once I get it working)**

```
PostsHelper
  def new_favourite
    if signed_in?
      return current_user.favourites.build
    else
      return Favourite.new
    end
  end
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<%= render :partial => 'shared/favourites/favourite_form', :locals => { :object => @post } %>
```

**_favourite_form.html.erb**

```
<% if signed_in? && current_user.favourited?(object) %>
  <%= render partial: 'shared/favourites/unfavourite', locals: { object: object } %>
<% else %>
  <%= render partial: 'shared/favourites/favourite', locals: { object: object } %>
<% end %>
```

**_favourite.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(new_favourite, remote: signed_in?) do |f| %>
    <div>
        <%= f.hidden_field :object_id, :value => object.id %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :object_type, :value => object.class.name.demodulize %>
    </div>
    <%= button_tag(:type => 'submit', :id => 'add_favourite') do %>
       Add to Favourites
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I want it to not do an ajax call (ie submit the add favourite form using a page reload) if the user is not signed in so that it will see the user is trying to access a protected page, will redirect them to login and upon success [when it redirects them back to where they were originally trying to go] it will add the favourite.

Can someone advise what I would need to change to make this possible.

---

EDIT:

Code updated to reflect current state.

After signing in it redirects back to `No route matches [GET] "/favourites"` because `favourites` are a nested resource under `users`.

---

EDIT 2:

The redirect works pretty much the same as in Rails Tutorial:

Redirect user to sign in page (signed_in_user):
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#code-correct_user_before_filter

Store location to redirect user back to:
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#code-friendly_forwarding_code
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#code-friendly_session_create

The only difference is that on my signin page I use a facebook omniauth link for the user to login but the redirection after logging in still works as expected.

Comment: This might get ugly in some parts of the code, but how about setting current_user to an empty user object (i.e. User.new) in your login logic? As I said, this can get ugly, since current_user.nil? will no longer check if a user is signed in and a lot of code might need some rewrite

Comment: Can we have a look at how your redirects work?

Comment: Sunxperous, I've added details of how the login redirect works.

Comment: I am confused by the redirections. What URL does the button generate? I would not have expected a redirect to sign in if there is no `/favourites` route. But since it redirects to sign in, how about modifying the stored location appropriately?

Comment: My mistake Sunxperous, I missed one of my routes off for favourites (I have it as a sub-level under user as well as at the top level. Both logged out and logged in favourite forms are generating the following form attributes `action="/favourites" method="post"`. Since it shows a form that the logged out user tries to submit, gets redirected to the login page and then upon successful login gets redirected back again I doubt the posted form will remain available so I don't think this is going to be possible.

Comment: I think my best option may be to just show a disabled button with a message and link underneath advising users to login and redirect them back to this point to then add the favourite once they are logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Use a helper method instead of `current_user.favourites.build`?

```
<%= form_for(new_favourite, remote: true) do |f| %>
```

Helper:

```
PostsHelper
  def new_favourite
    if signed_in?
      return current_user.favourites.build
    else
      return Favourite.new
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Not quite Sunxperous. I had to change `remote: true` to `remote: signed_in?` because otherwise it loads the sign in page in the ajax call. Even then though, after signing in, it redirects back to `No route matches [GET] "/favourites"` because `favourites` are a nested resource under `users`. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm. Does this mean that `return Favourite.new` is working fine, or am I right to say that as `favourites` are nested, so the form does not lead to a valid route? Perhaps you could update your code to reflect what you've changed. Anyway, my other suggestion is to pass the `Favourite` directly into `sign_in`, such that it saves immediately after the user signs in, in the same action. This might not be an elegant solution though.